# PHP: Change only a portion of a URL string?

Tags: php, string, url, explode

I’m working on a small hoppy project where I want to replace a specific page on a URL. Let me explain:

I’ve got the URL

> http://www.example.com/article/paragraph/low/

I want to keep the URL but replace the last segment `/low/` with `/high/` so the new URL is:

> http://www.example.com/article/paragraph/high/

I’ve tried different explode, split and splice but I just can’t seem to wrap my head around it and make it work. I can change the entire URL but not just the last segment and save it in a new variable.
I’m pretty confidence that it is a pretty straight forward case but I’ve never worked that much with arrays / string-manipulation in PHP so I’m pretty lost.

I guess that I have to first split the URL up in segments, using the "\" to separate it (I tried that but have problems by using `explode("\", $string))` and then replace the last `\low\` with `\high\`

Hope someone could help or point me in the right direction to what methods to use for doing this.

Sincere
Mestika

Comment: Are all those backslashes "`\`" meant to be frontslashes "`/`"?  hey are not interchangeable.

Comment: @Gordon Not a duplicate. Or at least not of that question.

Comment: @Alin correct. I confused parse_str with parse_url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You took \ for /.

```
$url = explode('/', rtrim($url, '/'));
if (end($url) == 'low') {
    $url[count($url)-1] = 'high';
}
$url = implode('/', $url) .'/';
```

Answer (score 4):

how about str_replace?

```
<?php
$newurl = str_replace('low', 'high', $oldurl);
?>
```

documentation;
http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

edit;
Rik is right; if your domain (or any other part of the url for that matter) includes the string "low", this will mess up your link.
So: if your url may contain multiple 'low' 's, you will have to add an extra indicator in the script. An example of that would be including the /'s in your str_replace.

Comment: Too inaccurate. What if the user's domain is loweredexpectations.com?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

class TestURL extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function testURL() {
        $URL =  'http://www.mydomain.com/article/paragraph/low/';
        $explode = explode('/', $URL);
        $explode[5] = 'high';
        $expected = 'http://www.mydomain.com/article/paragraph/high/';
        $actual = implode('/', $explode);
        $this->assertEquals($expected, $actual);
    }
}
```

--

```
phpunit simple-test.php 
PHPUnit 3.4.13 by Sebastian Bergmann.

.

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 4.75Mb

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

Comment: @using `split` "This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged."

Comment: Thanks Alin I did not know that + phpunit did not show me the warning. Thanks for the info. I updated the snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url) to split the URL into its components, modify them as required (here you can use [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) to split the path into its segments), and then rebuild the URL with [`http_build_url`](http://php.net/http_build_url).

Comment: I don't think using `parse_url` simplifies his problem. It's a very simple problem already, but he just doesn't know how to approach it.

Comment: @Alin Purcaru: It’s not about simplification but about correctness.

Comment: I guess it would make a bit of sense to use `parse_url` if he wants to use an `explode` approach. I had in mind a replace solution and for that it would be useless to change the url in any way.

Answer (score 0):

This will probably be enough:

```
$url = "http://www.mydomain.com/article/paragraph/low/";
$newUrl = str_replace('/low/', '/high/', $url);
```

or with regular expressions (it allows more flexibility)

```
$url = "http://www.mydomain.com/article/paragraph/low/";
$newUrl = preg_replace('/low(\/?)$/', 'high$1', $url);
```

Note that the string approach will replace any `low` segment and only if it's followed by a `/`. The regex approach will replace `low` only if it's the last segment and it may not be followed by a `/`.

Comment: The first snippet would replace "/low/" at any position in the URL, not only at the end.

Comment: @rik I know. I added an alternative if he doesn't want that.